# Algolia&Angular : NullInjectorError: No provider for NgAisInstantSearch

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am trying to add an algolia search field to my angular app but I still come across this error. I followed this tutorial ([link](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/resources/ui-and-ux-patterns/in-depth/autocomplete/angular/#results-page-with-autocomplete)) but I have the impression that there is an error but I cannot find it. In this deposit I have copied / pasted what they say : https://github.com/filol/algolia-test

I tried to add `NgAisInstantSearch` in the providers but I come across other errors and in their examples they do not (eg : [link example](https://github.com/algolia/angular-instantsearch/blob/develop/examples/e-commerce/src/app/app.module.ts))

**Error :**

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AutocompleteComponent -> NgAisInstantSearch]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AutocompleteComponent -> NgAisInstantSearch]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgAisInstantSearch!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59947:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74865:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74791:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74641:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74865:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74791:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74641:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85828:29)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:86894:16)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:87425:45)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what have you tried? You should be registering the `NgAisInstantSearch` as provider in the modue where it's used and inject the same in component constructor before using it,

Comment: Did you add `NgAisModule.forRoot()` as an import in the root of your app? This most likely is what registers that service and is found in the linked GitHub `algolia-test` project.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes and as you can see I put it on the test github but I have the same error

Comment: @nircraft For me I should not do it. It is not written anywhere in the doc and it is the role of `NgAisModule.forRoot()`. When I do it I have errors on the instantsearch library